# Load content over ajax by click and onload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page where I have a menu that makes an ajax call when clicking and it loads content in a div with a little animation with the footer. (as can be seen here: http://perishablepress.com/slide-fade-content/
I'm wondering if there is a way to have the first menu item to be loaded already when opening the page. My code:

```
<ul>
<li><a class="blog" href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
<li><a class="contact" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.blog').on('click', function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if ($('#ajax').is(':visible')) {
        $('#ajax').css({ display:'block' }).animate({ height:'0' }).empty();
    }
    $('#ajax').css({ display:'block' }).animate({ height:'200px' },function() {
        $('#loader').css({ border:'none', position:'relative', top:'24px', left:'48px', boxShadow:'none' }); 
        $('#ajax').load('blog.php ' + href, function() {
            $('#ajax').hide().fadeIn('slow').colorFade({ 'fadeColor': '#0e0e0e' }); }); }); }); });    



    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.contact').on('click', function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if ($('#ajax').is(':visible')) {
        $('#ajax').css({ display:'block' }).animate({ height:'0' }).empty();
    }
    $('#ajax').css({ display:'block' }).animate({ height:'600px' },function() {
        $('#loader').css({ border:'none', position:'relative', top:'24px', left:'48px', boxShadow:'none' }); 
        $('#ajax').load('contact.php ' + href, function() {
            $('#ajax').hide().fadeIn('slow').colorFade({ 'fadeColor': '#0e0e0e' });
        });
    });
});
});
```

So now I have to click "blog" or "contact" to have the content load, but I'd like to have "blog" loaded as default when opening the page!

And also: Is there a way to have not only the content, but also another version of jquery loaded, let's say when I click "contact" and my contact form works with another jquery version.

I hope somebody can help a super-noob like me!
Thanks  lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just trigger the click event manually for the `.blog` element using [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/#click) or [.trigger('click')](http://api.jquery.com/trigger).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.blog').on('click', function () {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if ($('#ajax').is(':visible')) {
            $('#ajax').css({
                display: 'block'
            }).animate({
                height: '0'
            }).empty();
        }
        $('#ajax').css({
            display: 'block'
        }).animate({
            height: '200px'
        }, function () {
            $('#loader').css({
                border: 'none',
                position: 'relative',
                top: '24px',
                left: '48px',
                boxShadow: 'none'
            });
            $('#ajax').load('blog.php ' + href, function () {
                $('#ajax').hide().fadeIn('slow').colorFade({
                    'fadeColor': '#0e0e0e'
                });
            });
        });
    }).click(); // trigger the click event for the blog event here
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your super-fast answer! that worked!! :)

Do you know if it is possible to also load another jquery instance with this method? So that I could have my jquery contact form on .contact ?